# kafka topic is not replicating when a node goes down

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running 3 nodes of kafka cluster version 3. I created a topic with 3 partitions and 3 replication-factors.I reduces the replicas to 2.

```
{"version":1,
  "partitions":[
     {"topic":"vpn7-test","partition":0,"replicas":[1,2]},
     {"topic":"vpn7-test","partition":1,"replicas":[1,2]},
     {"topic":"vpn7-test","partition":2,"replicas":[1,2]}
]}
```

`bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092 --reassignment-json-file kafka_replica_update.json --execute`

Now my topic properties is:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic vpn7-test --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092
Topic: vpn7-test        TopicId: 6WV4x3Q5SjW_nKRZdb0ZrA PartitionCount: 3       ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824,max.message.bytes=1000000000,unclean.leader.election.enable=true,retention.bytes=-1
        Topic: vpn7-test        Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2,1
        Topic: vpn7-test        Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2,1
        Topic: vpn7-test        Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2,1
```

After some period of time i stop kafka1 that is broker id 1.

And now topic schema is changed

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic vpn7-test --bootstrap-server kafka2:9092
Topic: vpn7-test        TopicId: 6WV4x3Q5SjW_nKRZdb0ZrA PartitionCount: 3       ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824,max.message.bytes=1000000000,unclean.leader.election.enable=true,retention.bytes=-1
        Topic: vpn7-test        Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2
        Topic: vpn7-test        Partition: 1    Leader: 2       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2
        Topic: vpn7-test        Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2
```

Why **Isr** is not updated to 2,3. Broker1 is dead and now i left with 2 brokers 2 and 3 the partition should automatically move from 1 to 3.

Comment: `"replicas":[1,2,3]` doesn't "reduce to 2" replicas. If you stop broker 1 and removed broker 3, then replica 2 is the only one left. What's the problem? And no, it can't replicate when ISR brokers are down

Comment: Sorry i wrote wrong i am modifying it again

Comment: Still, you removed broker 3 as a replica with the reassign script. And broker 1 is down, leaving only 2 as an ISR. What are you confused about?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka will not automatically migrate partitions to active brokers that the topic itself doesn't know about.

You'd need to add broker 3 back into the replicas array using the reassign tool again

Comment: From your point kafka will not maintain/update the replicas if broker goes down(the one who was handling). Because I was thinking that we have one more broker(broker 3) which was not handling partition earlier , and kafka will update the ISR automatically to broker 3